# Disable multiple select2 field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I create a checkbox field and multiple select2 field, and I enable the checkbox field but which change is not affect the multiple select field. I need to disable the multiple select field after disabling the checkbox. is this possible? I tried the below code.

```js
$('select option').prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable select2 using **$(".sel2").prop("disabled", true)**
for more detail see the document https://select2.org/appearance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sel2').select2();
});
$(document).on('click','#disable',function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
  //console.log("in");
    $(".sel2").prop("disabled", true);
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel2" name="state">
  <option value="AL">one</option>
  <option value="AL">two</option>
</select>
<select class="sel2" name="state">
  <option value="AL">one</option>
  <option value="AL">two</option>
</select>
<select class="sel2" name="state">
  <option value="AL">one</option>
  <option value="AL">two</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="disable" value="Disable select" /> Disable
```

if you want to enable and disable select2 fields on checked and unchecked of check box

```
$(document).on('click','#disable',function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(".sel2").prop("disabled", true);
  }else{
    $(".sel2").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently refering to specific options of the select, I think you need to target the parent select element.

And according to the [documentation](https://select2.github.io/select2/), see ***Select2 Disabled Mode***, you need to do it like this:

```js
$("select").select2("enable", false);
```

Nvm, I see I mentioned the old documentation, parent element thing was correct.

Comment: Actually you are referring to an old version of the documentation. According to the recent version, the accepted answer is the correct way.

Comment: Aw no! Thanks for mentioning. Then they have improved it the right way! :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#disable").change(function() {

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("select").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
})
```

you can use is checked to checking if checkbox is cecked or not